# How to make a text file of Files/Folders on a certain Drive?

Tags: windows

I need some help. I would like to make a text file of all the files and folders on a certain drive, how can I do this?. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
X:
dir /s /b > allfiles.txt
```

That will get you a list of all pathname for directories for which you have access.  Does that do it?

Comment: I tried that command Alan, and it said Access is denied.

Comment: Run the CMD as the administrator and it should.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way might be:

> C:
>
> cd\
>
> dir /b /s >filename.txt